# SQL error 1677 cannot be converted from type 'datetime' to type 'varchar(255)'

Tags: mysql

I got error 1677 on my slave.

```
Last_Errno: 1677
Last_Error: Column 25 of table 'db.table' cannot be converted from type 'datetime' to type 'varchar(255)'
```

I'm try to solved this by copy the same db from master to the slave, but after I restart the slave it still showing the same error. I've done too walk around to find the solution. one of them are set `slave_type_conversions=all_non_lossy` but, I didnt sure to take this because it running well before.

running `show create table db.table\G` on both master and duplicate showing same output without any different.

**Master create table**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: machines
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `machines` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TID` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DisplayType` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OnlineStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temperature` float(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Signal` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellStatus` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Volume` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DisplaySize` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeployStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `DeployLocation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageLocation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAC` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMEI` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetworkCode` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetworkName` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppVersion` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FaultNotifyRuleID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID Management Strategi Alarm Yopoint',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `machines_tid_unique` (`TID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**Master Character and Collation DB**

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_general_ci      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**Slave create table**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: machines
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `machines` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TID` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DisplayType` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OnlineStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temperature` float(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Signal` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellStatus` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Volume` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DisplaySize` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeployStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `DeployLocation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageLocation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAC` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMEI` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetworkCode` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetworkName` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppVersion` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FaultNotifyRuleID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID Management Strategi Alarm Yopoint',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `machines_tid_unique` (`TID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**Slave Character and Collation DB**

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_general_ci      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**Questions**

> Column 25 of table 'atlas.machines' cannot be converted from type 'datetime' to type 'varchar(255)'

There is anything I can do with this?

Comment: A [mcve] would help

Comment: thank you @Charlieface, is there anything not clear enough on my question?

Comment: `show create table db.table` and `SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;` on both master and slave would be a start

Comment: I updated my question with both command, thank you for your suggestion. is it clear enough? @Charlieface

Comment: Show us a sample of the "garbage in".

Comment: @RickJames sorry, I never heard garbage in before. could you repeat the question please?

Comment: Which is column 25?

Comment: It should be `FaultNotifyRuleID` I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done by:

1. reset the slave
2. setting the last binlog on slave instance
3. try to stop and start the slave
4. (optional) delete another binlog on master except the updated one